# How to run javaFx application against gtk 3 libs?

Tags: java, gtk, javafx

How to force javaFx application use gtk3 libs? I know that SWT allows to set `SWT_GTK3=1` environmental variable for that purpose. Is there any similar possibility / workaround for javaFx?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

New feature ([8087516: Conditional support for GTK 3 on Linux](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087516)) allows using either GTK v2 or 3 with JavaFX. The default has not changed: GTK 2 will be used by default.

Switch GTK versions by setting the following properties:

```
// Output the version detected and used
-Djdk.gtk.verbose=true 

// Toggle the preferred version to GTK 3
-Djdk.gtk.version=3
```

More details can be found on the OpenJDK [mailing list thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-May/019100.html).

---

Previous versions of JavaFX used GTK2 libraries. See the [related issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35264) for details. JavaFX bugs are now at:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088966 (closed as duplicate)
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089584 (open)

The last issue has a comment:

> Since mixing GTK2 and GTK3 in the same application causes this
> problem, we might have to deliver two native libraries, one for GTK2
> and one for GTK3.

Comment: I'm running Azul JRE FX 1.8.0_272 and apparently the default has been changed (or even more likely, there is some auto-detection going on).

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution. JavaFX has it's own rendering framework. As far as I understand it, that is based on OpenGL and doesn't use any native code. Without this, JavaFX wouldn't be able to style the UI using CSS and visual effects.

If you really need this, then you have to write your own library that emulates Gtk3 using the JavaFX scene graph and other tools. That won't allow you to access native components, though.

Comment: I got a very simple app - https://gist.github.com/ibuziuk/8351313. After running it and using "sudo pldd [pid] | grep gtk" in the terminal, I got an output with gtk2 libs. What I want to check is, whether javaFx compatible with gtk3?

Comment: JavaFX uses Java which contains AWT which, on some platforms, is linked against GTK. That doesn't mean you can create JavaFX UIs with it.

Comment: Yes, but there is a possibility to embed javaFx component into Swing/AWT/SWT component via FXCanvas and JFXpanels. It works fine with    gtk2 but not with gtk3. So, I have created a bug to the javaFx team - https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35264 .

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to talk to the Java-Gnome guys. They implemented their library that makes it possible to write Java apps with GTK interfaces. Should be a possible extension to also support JavaFX. http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/