# Java/Swing: Desktop.open() causes GTK-ERROR

Tags: java, swing, gtk, awt, desktop

I am currently developing a `Swing` Desktop application. This application is also using a tray icon which is handled by [`SystemTray` of dorkbox](https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray).

Now I need to open a file with the default application. To achieve this I am using the `Desktop.open()` method of `AWT` like this.

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    System.out.println("Get desktop.");
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    System.out.println("Got desktop.");
    desktop.open(file);
}
```

But now here comes the problem: On some devices (which apparently have GTK2 and GTK3 installed this few lines make application crash - the program crashes while executing the `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` line with a `gtk-error ** gtk+ 2.x symbols detected. using gtk+ 2.x and gtk+ 3 is not supported`.

To be honest, I have no clue, what is going wrong here - but if only GTK3 is installed the application runs like a charm. The `SystemTray` seems to be using GTK3 as well because I did not explicitly set it up to use GTK2.
So, what's causing this mix of GTK2 and 3? Is there a way to force the `Desktop` class to use the *right* version of GTK (the same, as being used by the rest of the application)?

Comment: If GTK 2 and GTK 3 have some library files with the same name (which I’m guessing they do), and both are in the library path, I would expect any GTK 3 application to report this error.

Comment: Apparently this is not the case. The interesting question is: Why does one part of `AWT` use `GTK3` as one other part of `swing` uses `GTK2` (or vice versa).

Comment: How is your application started?  I’m tempted to suggest modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your environment.

Comment: Im starting the application simply with `java -jar application.jar`

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093723/how-to-run-javafx-application-against-gtk-3-libs and also http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/283 and http://www.infoworld.com/article/3035505/java/java-9-to-address-gtk-gui-pains-on-linux.html .

Answer (score 2):

It won't resolve your current problem but there is another way to open file with the default application.

On Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\SomeFolder\Somefile.txt");
```

On Mac and Linux:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open /folder/file.txt");
```

Hope it will help you, if you won't resolve your current problem.

Comment: But this won't work, if the user has not installed the xdg utilities, will it?

Comment: On Mac it's just `open`, not `xdg-open`.

Comment: But relying on `xdg-open` does not seem to be the best way, is this does not have to be installed...

Comment: @D. Krauchanka: 
At my machine the xdg-open command is not exectued when I call it like this from my java, but when I try to execute the exact same command in a terminal window, it works. Where is the problem?