# Java Runtime exec() not working

Tags: java, bash, shell, runtime, xdgutils

I try to execute a shell command via `java` like this

```
if (Program.isPlatformLinux())
{
    exec = "/bin/bash -c xdg-open \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    exec2 = "xdg-open \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    System.out.println(exec);
}
else
{
    //other code
}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exec);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exec2);
```

but nothing happens at all. When I execute this code it prints `/bin/bash -c xdg-open "/home/user/Desktop/file.txt"` in the console, but does not open the file. I have also tried to call the bash first and then the `xdg-open`-command, but there is not change.

What's the problem here and how can I solve this?

EDIT: The output of the calling looks like this:

> xdg-open "/home/user/Desktop/files/einf in a- und b/allg fil/ref.txt"
>   xdg-open: unexpected argument 'in'

But this seeems very strange to me - why is the command seperatet before the `in` even the entire path is set in quotation marks?

Comment: Try checking if there is some error by printing the process output as [shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console). Maybe you get a more specific error to work on.

Comment: @BackSlash I followed your advice and added the results from this to my original post.

Comment: *"einf in a- und b"* is this a folder name containing spaces?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands) for why `Runtime.exec(String)` fails when the command contains quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you don't need `xdg-open` to do this.
You can use the java platform-agnostic [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.open("/path/to/file.txt");
}
```

---

**Update**

If the standard approach still gives issues, you can pass the parameters as an array since `Runtime.exec` does not invoke a shell and therefore does not support or allow quoting or escaping:

```
String program;
if (Program.isPlatformLinux())
{
    program = "xdg-open";
} else {
    program = "something else";
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{program, file.getAbsolutePath()});
```

Comment: This was my first approch. But it does not seem to work:
`xdg-open/home/user/Desktop/files/einf\ in\ a-\ und\ b/allg\ fil/ref.txt
xdg-open: unexpected argument 'in\'`

Comment: You need to escape the backslash. Check the answer again

Comment: I cannot use the `Desktop` class as it seems to crash the entire application at some devices (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554515/java-swing-desktop-open-causes-gtk-error)

Comment: Your code is also not working, with the same error as above.

Comment: Alright, this seem to be working. So you have an idea how to fix the real problem, that the Desktop class is crashing the application on some devices?