# Opening a PDF in java using Linux Terminal

Tags: java, linux, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF file in Linux with the xdg-open command in java.

```
String[] command = {"xdg-open","\""+path+"\""}
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null);
p.waitFor();
```

When I run the code in terminal nothing happens even tho if I type it in terminal:

```
xdg-open path
```

it opens the PDF.
Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40569083/2633917](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40569083/2633917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not escape the path: if the program was called, it was with an invalid path (`"path"` and not `path`).

```
String[] command = {"xdg-open", path}
```

The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null);` will use `ProcessBuilder` internally which, in the case of Linux, should invoke the system command [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).